# mitmproxy: does one have to set proxy server to local?

Tags: python, proxy

For using mitmproxy do I have to set my proxy to localhost or does mitmproxy work immediately when I start it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set your browser proxy to localhost:8080.

Answer (score 0):

By default, mitmproxy server is installed to listen for 127.0.0.1:8080 (or localhost:8080)
To let mitmproxy work, you have to:

1. Start mitmproxy
2. Set up 127.0.0.1:8080 or localhost:8080 as a proxy server in your browser settings.